# Even though I'm connected through VPN sites still see my private IP address

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Ubuntu 16.04, Kernel: 4.4.0-72-generic

I decided to test out the NordVPN because my internet provider blocks a lot of sites. I did everything according to [Their website](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/)  and I'm able to connect without a problems

The problem is that even though I'm connected - the sites like thepiratebay are still blocked and sites like [WhatsMyIp](https://whatismyipaddress.com/) still see my real IP.

I'm pretty sure it's system fault because I tested the connection on another laptop (Windows) and on the Android Phone and everything is working correctly there.

I disabled `WebRTC` and I'm using `dnscrypt`. I was thinking that it might have be a browser fault - and installed fresh instance of Firefox (I'm using chrome) but nothing changed.

The weird thing is that the `traceroute` is showing the traffic is going with the right gateway

`traceroute`

```
traceroute to thepiratebay.se (104.31.16.3), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.7.7.1 (10.7.7.1)  15.778 ms  36.980 ms  36.996 ms
 2  h88-150-133-73.host.redstation.co.uk (88.150.133.73)  37.067 ms  37.066 ms  37.064 ms
 3  105.zone.5.c.dc10.redstation.co.uk (185.20.96.165)  36.935 ms  36.930 ms  36.926 ms
 4  be201.asr01.thn.as20860.net (62.128.210.218)  36.923 ms  36.920 ms  36.916 ms
 5  linx-juniper.as13335.net (195.66.225.179)  50.898 ms  50.893 ms  50.846 ms
 6  104.31.16.3 (104.31.16.3)  50.795 ms  20.391 ms  19.316 ms
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.7.7.1        0.0.0.0         UG    50     0        0 tun0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp3s0
h5-152-210-242. 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   600    0        0 wlp3s0
10.7.7.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     50     0        0 tun0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 wlp3s0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp3s0
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

The reason was the ipv6 - NordVPN does not support it (yet), and somehow some sites were able to detect my IPV6 address. Disabling it fixed my problems.